# SSL Site Setup HTML not making sense

Tags: ssl

I have been searching the internet for two days and I am stuck.  I understand that I can purchase an SSL certificate to make my site work for HTTPS so that it is more secure and all that jazz.

My question is do I have to do anything special on the HTML/PHP pages I create for this site, like some PHP call to open a session, or does the fact that there is an SSL Cert on the server mean I don't have to change anything on the HTML pages?

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I can't find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its primary the setup of the server, e.g. that you have to make the site accessible by SSL (port etc) and configure the certificates.

But maybe you need to make adjustments to your HTML etc too, so that all resources (images, script, css..) will be loaded by SSL too, e.g. all these includes should be either be done with site-relative links or with explicite https:// links. In case the site gets served with both https and http you might also use protocol-relative links, e.g. //www.example.com/index.html will be served with http if the current protocol is http and with https if you currently use https.

Comment: Steffen - thanks for the feedback.  This is perfect.  Thank you so much!